# PHP - Confusing Performance Issue getting data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Using PHP/MySQLi I wanted to extract some data to an array. The data is a few megabytes in size:

[image]

The code to get the table dump of this data follows:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

 $q =  "SELECT * FROM mytable";
 if (!$result = $mysqli->query($q)) {
      echo "Error: Our query failed to execute and here is why: \n";
      echo "Query: " . $query . "\n";
      echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
      echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
      return $ret;
    }
if ($result->num_rows === 0) {
   $ret = 0;
   return $ret;
  }

$ret = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
  array_push($ret, $row);
} 

echo  mb_strlen(serialize((array)$ret), '8bit');
```

When executing the following code I got:

[image]

But it said **tried to allocate  28672 bytes** which is nowhere near the limit. Why is this?

Comment: What line produce the error?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

Comment: Your query use `SELECT *` but when you measure size use `{row_1,row_2,row_n}` Are more colmuns there? Are all those columns strings?

Comment: I calculated all the columns, all are integers

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way.

You've got $100. You go to the candy store, and decide to buy 200 $1 candy bars, one-by-one (your `while` loop).

The first 100 purchases are going to go through, but the next time you try buying a $1 candy bar, you're going to get told "you tried to spend a dollar, but you've already spent $100".

PHP is reporting the amount of memory your *last* instruction attempted to use. In this case, it's probably the `array_push($ret, $row);` call.

Comment: Ok but the error is saying you can't spend more than $100. (tried to spend $18)

Comment: @BDillan It's telling you "You just tried to use X additional bytes of memory, but that amount puts you over your limit." Don't overthink it.

Comment: @ceejayoz But why a dataset with 2 Mb cause you to reach the limit?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The answer to *that* needs a bit of a dive into PHP's internals, but the TL;DR is "arrays take up a lot more space than just their raw data". https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html (Plus, your query etc. are likely taking up memory space, as well. You can experiment with logging [`memory_get_usage`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) values to figure out where it's all going, if you like.)

Comment: So what you are saying is that PHP cannot handle more than (lets say 2mb) of sql data?

That's depressing

Comment: No, that's not what he's saying. Increase the size of the memory allocated to PHP when you hit a limit like this (if you can). It looks like your limit is currently set to 128M so try bumping it to 512M and see what happens. I would also limit the amount of data your query is retrieving. If you don't need all of the columns don't use the `SELECT *`. Depending on the amount of data each row contains the amount of data required could be very large.

Comment: @BDillan The article I linked has one potential approach - using a `SplFixedArray`. In general, there are better ways than iterating an entire large dataset into an array, though. What's the goal of loading it all into an array here?